# How to compare two dates in Xsl?

Tags: xml, xslt

How to check if date in the xml file is over two years from today in xsl 1.0?
here is my code, thank you

xml file:

```
   <forms>
      <form>
         <date>20140105</date>
      </form>
    </forms>
```

xsl file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
<html>
            <script language="JScript" implements-prefix="myJavaScript">
               <![CDATA[
                  function GetCurrentDateTime(){
                    var dateObj = new Date();
                    var month = ('0' + (dateObj.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
                    var date = ('0' + dateObj.getDate()).slice(-2);
                    var year = dateObj.getFullYear()-2;
                    var newDate = year  + month  + date;
                    return newDate
                  }
               ]]>
            </script>
    <xsl:for-each select="forms/form">
        <xsl:if test="date &lt;= GetCurrentDateTime ">
            <!-- in progress -->
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no `current-date` function in XPath/XSLT 1, there is no date datatype in XSLT/XPath 1. So usually, to use or compare dates or make date computation you use extensions from a host language or platform like Java or .NET or Python or PHP, all which very much depends on the XSLT 1 processor used. Which XSLT 1 processor exactly do you use?

Comment: Well, if you use JScript then pass the input value from the XML (e.g. `20140105`) to JScript and convert it to a `Date` there and do the comparison there with JScript.

Comment: Ok ill try this, thanks

Comment: `<xsl:if text="GetCurrentDateTime(Date)">` Is it possible read the function like this?

Comment: On the XPath side youcan call e.g. `myJavaScript:compareDate(date)` to pass in the XML `date` element to an extension function called compareDate` implemented in your J(ava)Script set up for the prefix `myJavaScript`. How you deal with that in J(ava)Script exactly then depends on the used XSLT processor and its API, in MSXML it is different to XslCompiledTransform.